# Does GCP SDK downloads the file when calling copyTo method from the Blob object?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

Given the example on the Google Cloud documentation:

```java
CopyWriter copyWriter = blob.copyTo(destBucket, destBlob);
Blob copiedBlob = copyWriter.getResult();
boolean deleted = blob.delete();
```

Does calling the `copyTo` method downloads the file to the local machine and then uploads it to the new destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CopyTo API does not download the object. Both the source and destination are objects in buckets and are copied by Cloud Storage backends. This can be verified by looking at the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/#Objects). There is no mechanism provided to download/upload data for this API.